# C++ unresovled external symbol link error related with name mangling?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compilation, static-libraries, name-mangling

all

i created a static lib project with VS 2010 sp1, and simply defined a class with a member function (code snippet):

.h:

```
namespace puphttp{
    class CRequester
    {
     public:
     void RequesterUpdate();
    };
}
```

.cpp:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Requester.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace puphttp{
    void CRequester::RequesterUpdate()
    {
        cout<<"updating";
    }
}
```

at last i linked the lib file and tried to invoke the following code:

```
puphttp::CRequester c;
c.RequestUpdate();
```

the following link error occur as i compile:
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl puphttp::CRequester::RequestUpdate(void)" **(?RequestUpdate@CRequest@puphttp@@QEAAXXZ)**

then i used dumpbin to check the actual function name in my lib, it's:
**(?RequestUpdate@CRequest@puphttp@@QAEXXZ)**

so the difference is **QEAAXXZ** vs **QAEXXZ**, i didn't have time to get into name mangling rule yet, so any quick answer? really much appreciated.

Comment: This may help but I'm not familiar with VC++ name decoration issues: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B_name_mangling

Comment: I do not know why it is voted to close. This question is suitable.

Comment: You sure you have linked it properly ?

Comment: Actually i had some existing static library projects in the same solution, they are all working fine and the symbols exported from them are all QEAAXXZ unlike my own lib, and i did a thorough compiling settings comparison of my project and the existing ones, but when i fixed all the differences the problem still exists.